# android.app.RemoteServiceException: on Android V 7 and & 7.1

Tags: android, exception, notification-listener

I am using a NotificationListener in a Job service to read the WhatsApp notification messages. It works fine all other OS versions than android v7 and v7.1.   In these devices, app crashes once a day I think. I cant reproduce the crash , I am getting this error log "android.app.RemoteServiceException:" from playstore .

```
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1813)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run `(ZygoteInit.java:1518)`

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

I have searched a lot but I can't find any solutions.  I am not creating any notifications, Just uses NotificationListener. At least I need catch this exception. I have gone through a lot of results regarding android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package. But nothing helped.

Comment: I have the same problem. If you solve it, I please to notify in this page the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131759/remoteserviceexception-error/50132681?noredirect=1#comment87290829_50132681