# RemoteServiceException Error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-console-developer, android-vitals

I have a lot of abnormal arrests, but I not understand
how this is possible, because don't understand the origin of the 
problem. 
This is the log of abnormal arrest:

> android.app.RemoteServiceException:
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1881) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
>   (Zygote.java:327)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Other information is that the problem is more showed on 
devices with Android:7 or more..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if my problem is the exact same problem as this one. I started getting crash reports on google play just like this. For example

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1881)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I started seeing this around build 189 and did not see this error before 185

So [this github checkin still did not have it](https://github.com/marchold/DeliveryDroid_v3/commit/065534f2e1cba4750ca0aead74bab783727cf6ea)

And [this github checkin had the bug for sure](https://github.com/marchold/DeliveryDroid_v3/commit/037300b4fc289c2bd7ee650ac38a56c862806906)

I was did make some changes related to a foreground service so I am suspecting my issue relates to

[Issue Tracker:  Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072)

[Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425584/context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-call-service-startforeground)

---- EDIT ----

My issue did turn out to be that I was calling startForegroundService which was not needed because my app was not in the background when it did this.

For sure the issue has been resolved by [this commit](https://github.com/marchold/DeliveryDroid_v3/commit/befa0a956b7eaf62cd7951381d3c6fa704db6a0e)

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information to diagnose this properly.

However, this is an "internal" exception that gets thrown when the looper attempts to handle a "SCHEDULE_CRASH" message.   I think that happens when another activity calls `ActivityThread.ApplicationThread.scheduleCrash` ... but this is not at all clear from the Android source code.

I am guessing that this a result some native application "bailing out".  There is typically an app specific message to go with the exception, but it seems to be missing in your case.

Comment: Stephen C Yes I know, the message is not shown. For this problem I don't know how start to solve it.. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Start by figuring out what native application might be running ... and crashing.   (I'm not an Android expert, and I can't help you with that.  I'm just reading the source code corresponding to the stacktrace you provided ...)